# Count amount of words, characters, newlines in C

Tags: c, do-while

[image]
I know it is not recommended to post code as an image, since I am getting a formatting error when trying to post code on here. Anyway, I am trying to write a simple C program to count number of words, characters, newlines using do while loop. However, the output is not as expected. Please help!

Comment: What ARE you getting?

Comment: See that little squiggle under the `a` on line 9? That's trying to tell you something. You're using an uninitialized variable. I think you need the `a=getchar()` stuff at the start of the loop rather than the end.

Comment: What is the value of `a` on your first iteration through the `do` loop? Perhaps a `while ((a = getchar()) != EOF) { ... }` would be in order?

Comment: @IgorRivin . For example, when I input hello world, the output is the number of characters 1, the number of character 2, the number of character 3, ... the number of characters 10.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a do-while, you should try using while. Since your code starts off by checking whether a is any of your if cases, it goes to the else case, and increments the New line variable. If possible, could you share the output screen.

Comment: For example, when I input hello world, the output is the number of characters 1, the number of character 2, the number of character 3, ... the number of characters 10. the same problem happens with count amount of words. the prompt is to use do-while loop. Sorry!